# Как создать многомерный массив java типа ключ-значение?

Tags: java, массивы

Как на java создать такой массив как здесь в примере на пхп?

```
$arr2 = array(
                'Авто' => array(
                                'KIA',
                                'BMW',
                                'MAZDA',
                                'OPEL'
                                ),
                'Краска' => array(
                                    'Красная',
                                    'Зеленая',
                                    'Черная'
                                    )
                );
```

Comment: Тянуть код с пхп - это вообще жесть. Следующий щаг - HTML to JAVA. Откройте для себя коллекции и будет Вам счастье. Там одних только коровых на любой вкус и цвет, а если еще апачевские да иже с ними... вообще про массивы забудете, что, между прочим, прямо указано в оф.документации джава, т.е. рекомендовано использовать коллекции вместо массивов. Добро пожаловать в мир объектно-ориентированного и функционального программирования, он красив и могуч))

Comment: Дмитрий, я не тяну код с пхп на яву, а использую здесь этот пример для того, чтобы быстро и наглядно показать людям что мне нужно получить. вот и все.Komdosh  вот дал отличный ответ, а не развел пустую демагогию.  З:Ы: Я прекрасно знаю ООП, но в яве новичок.

Comment: Ничего против этого ответа не имею. Все верно. Но я вам вообще-то про коллекции и сказал или HashMap перестал быть коллекцией? Ну, простите, код не написал, подумал, что идеи достаточно...

Comment: И еще...Решение, конечно, отличное, но имейте в виду, что Ваш List,который вы затолкали в Map,намертво привязан к массиву, поскольку, собственно, непосредственно из него создан с помощью Arrays.asList. И это хорошее решение до тех пор,пока вы не захотите изменять размеры этого самого листа.В этом случае вы получите исключение, потому как размер массива менять нельзя, а в данном случае это и есть хорошо замаскированный массив. И еще то,что вы делаете, называется мультимэп:1 ключ-много значений. И это именно то, о чем я говорил - коллекции Guava,Apach такое умеют из коробки.Может будет полезно))

Comment: Спасибо) буду иметь ввиду. Мне просто срочно нужно было решение и HashMap подошел для той задачи.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

С помощью Map и List

```
Map<String, List<String>> arr2 = new HashMap<>();
arr2.put("Авто", Arrays.asList("KIA", "BMW", "MAZDA", "OPEL"));
arr2.put("Краска", Arrays.asList("Красная", "Зелёная", "Чёрная"));
```